# What explains the digitization effect experienced by Stevens in one of his "flashbacks"?

Tags: source-code

In the movie Source Code, during one of his "flashbacks," Stevens experiences the world appear to disintegrate, and "digitize."  While watching the movie, you get the impression this is the result of a flaw/bug/glitch/whatever in the Source Code program.

But by the end of the movie we learn that the "flashbacks" were reality in an alternate timeline/universe

so it could not have been a simple glitch in the recreation of the flashback.  What explains this disintegration/digitization effect he experienced?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Though I don't perfectly remember the scene, you might explain it not as a glitch in the alternate universe in itself, but in the connection of Stevens to this universe, which is still only established by (faulty) technology.